# .ssh/rc not working

Tags: ssh, terminal, rc

Whenever I ssh to my desktop, I change `$TERM` to `ansi` so that ssh works better with the Windows terminal. I decided to create `~/.ssh/rc` and add `TERM=ansi` to it. The problem is, after I ssh into my desktop, the terminal type is still `msys` instead of `ansi`. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get the TERM setting to work from ~/.ssh/rc either.

I could get it to work by changing the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

followed by a restart of sshd and taking into account the warning from `man sshd_config`,

> PermitUserEnvironment
>
> Specifies whether ~/.ssh/environment and environment= options in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys are processed by sshd(8).  The default is “no”.  Enabling environment processing may enable users to bypass access restrictions in some configurations using mechanisms such as LD_PRELOAD.

Then I created the `~/.ssh/environment` file and added the line,

```
TERM=ansi
```

logged back in and it worked.

EDIT:

This won't help much, but setting the TERM on the command line before calling ssh (on Linux) does set the term type on the remote end.

```
TERM=ansi ssh test@home.local
test@home.local ~ $ echo $TERM
ansi
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the client is running Windows, so I can't change the terminal type client-side. Turning on `PermitUserEnvironment` worked, though!

Comment: @James, deleted my post - until it is resolved, it didn't contribute to the question...let me know if you figure anything out, i'm stumped too...

Comment: @Pete, np, something strange is going on because you can,

    export TERM=ansi
    echo $TERM

in the rc file and see that it prints 'ansi' but then ends up with the TERM still being set as 'msys'.

Comment: @James what is your OS?

Comment: Linux - Gentoo and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up your variable, you should export it so it will get into your terminal that is `exec`-ed afterwards:

```
export TERM=ansi
```

Comment: I added that to `.ssh/rc` before posting the question, and it didn't work.